# Java - Replace one character with multiple characters

Tags: java, replace, parameters, character

I've been trying to replace one character with multiple ones. 
Currently I have this:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String test = "This is a test.";
    String output = test.replace('i', '!');
    System.out.println(output);
  }

}
```

The problem is that I want to replace "i" with "gheri" for example. I've been trying to put 2+ characters in the second parameter, but it doesn't work. I can only change it into something with 1 chars length. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String`'s [`replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "This is a test.";
    String output = test.replace("i", "gheri");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output is

```
Thgheris gheris a test.
```

Comment: For future readers, the trick is in the double quotes for a char sequence vs. the single quotes for a char.

Answer (score 3):

`String` has an overloaded [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method that accepts `Strings` instead of chars

```
String output = test.replace("i", "gheri");
```